# diagonal problem in octagon

Tags: geometry

[image]
 I have not understand the question clearly.  Can you give me hints (with figure) so I can move on .

Comment: For each vertex $2$ of $5$ diagonals originating from that vertex belong to $A$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at a single vertex. How many diagonals can be drawn from that vertex? Of those, how many are not parallel to any side of the octagon (that is, how many belong to $B$)? What does this tell you, given the rotational symmetry of the figure?

As an alternate approach, we may determine these explicitly with combinatorics and pictures. There are $8$ vertices, so $\binom{8}{2}=28$ line segments that connect pairs of vertices. Of these, $8$ are edges, leaving $28-8=20$ diagonals. The diagonals that are not parallel to any edge are those between opposite vertices (only $4$ such diagonals) and those between vertices with a common neighbor ($8$ of these, forming two squares). Hence, $B$ has $12$ diagonals, and $A$ has $20-12=8$ diagonals (which you can actually draw in sequence without lifting your pencil).